# Xcode 5.1.1 and Xcode 6.1 crash when creating a new Project /File/Workspace on Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: macos, xcode

Xcode 5.1.1 and Xcode 6.1  crash on create new Project /File/Workspace on Yosemite 10.10.2

I'm running xcode 6.1 and 5.1.1 on OS X Yosemite 10.10.2.
I'm unable to create a new project, as you can see bellow it just says 'loading'

Please suggest to fix this issue

> process: Xcode [2792]
>
> Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
>
> Identifier: com.apple.dt.Xcode
>
> Version: 5.1.1 (5085)
>
> Build Info: IDEFrameworks-5085000000000000~10
>
> Code Type: X86-64 (Native)
>
> Parent Process: ??? [1]
>
> Responsible: Xcode [2792]
>
> User ID: 501
>
> Date/Time: 2015-01-11 22:07:07.203 +0530
>
> OS Version: Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C94b)
>
> Report Version: 11
>
> Anonymous UUID: C09A26EF-E9EA-9CD0-E670-228AA19E0BA7
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 13000 seconds
>
> Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
>
> Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information:
>
> Sending goNextOrFinish: to from
>
> ProductBuildVersion: 5B1008
>
> UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: sortColumn)
>
> UserInfo: (null)
>
> Hints:
>
> 0: Sending goNextOrFinish: to from
>
> Backtrace:
>
> 0 0x00007fff91a14654 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
>
> 1 0x000000010e6ecb10 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
>
> 2 0x00007fff9361976e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
>
> 3 0x00007fff918fc876 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] (in CoreFoundation)
>
> 4 0x00007fff8f89478e -[FI_TNodeViewSettings setListViewSortColumn:] (in FinderKit)
>
> 5 0x00007fff8f890d0e -[FI_TNodeViewSettings refreshListViewSettings] (in FinderKit)
>
> 6 0x00007fff8f8911bb -[FI_TNodeViewSettings refreshSettings:] (in FinderKit)
>
> 7 0x00007fff8f8914c4 -[FI_TNodeViewSettings initWithNode:] (in FinderKit)
>
> 8 0x00007fff8f88fc56 +[FI_TNodeViewSettings settingsForNode:] (in FinderKit)
>
> 9 0x00007fff8f93204c -[FI_TBrowserContainerController nodeViewSettings] (in FinderKit)
>
> 10 0x00007fff8f9317ed -[FI_TBrowserContainerController initWithWindowState:targetPath:containerDelegate:] (in FinderKit)
>
> 11 0x00007fff8f8bd13e -[FIFinderViewGutsController _internalSetTargetPath:withViewStyle:] (in FinderKit)
>
> 12 0x00007fff8f8b8e8b -[FIFinderViewGutsController forceContainerToExist] (in FinderKit)
>
> 13 0x00007fff8f8b98ff -[FIFinderViewGutsController prepareToShow] (in FinderKit)
>
> 14 0x00007fff8f8c278e -[FIFinderView viewWillMoveToWindow:] (in FinderKit)
>
> 15 0x00007fff8d322b2e -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
>
> 16 0x00007fff91935385 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
>
> 17 0x00007fff91934a89 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation)
>
> 18 0x00007fff8da139c4 __21-[NSView _setWindow:]_block_invoke733 (in AppKit)
>
> 19 0x00007fff8d323693 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
>
> 20 0x00007fff8d3209e3 -[NSView addSubview:] (in AppKit)
>
> 21 0x00007fff8d66d82a -[NSBox setContentView:] (in AppKit)
>
> 22 0x00007fff8d8c76b5 -[NSSavePanel(NSSavePanelLayout) _layoutViewsVerticallyAndResizeWindowToLastExpandedSize:accessoryViewHeight:] (in AppKit)
>
> 23 0x00007fff8d8b27b0 -[NSSavePanel _initPanelCommon] (in AppKit)
>
> 24 0x00007fff8d8b1afa -[NSSavePanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] (in AppKit)
>
> 25 0x00007fff8d8b0fd9 +[NSSavePanel _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel] (in AppKit)
>
> 26 0x000000010f9a36ee -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant configuredOpenPanel] (in IDEKit)
>
> 27 0x00000001163b7be3 -[Xcode3ProjectTemplateCompletionAssistant configuredSavePanel] (in Xcode3UI)
>
> 28 0x000000010f9a38db -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant beginSheetModalForWindow:] (in IDEKit)
>
> 29 0x000000010f9a3d96 -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant finishWithCompletionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
>
> 30 0x000000010f7f9c63 -[IDEAssistantWindowController goNextOrFinish:] (in IDEKit)
>
> 31 0x00007fff90c89cd7 _os_activity_initiate (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
>
> 32 0x00007fff8d4da541 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
>
> 33 0x000000010ec50f85 __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
>
> 34 0x000000010e6ec842 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
>
> 35 0x000000010eb1eb0e -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
>
> 36 0x00007fff8d4da340 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] (in AppKit)
>
> 37 0x00007fff8d6b014b __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
>
> 38 0x00007fff90c89cd7 _os_activity_initiate (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
>
> 39 0x00007fff8d522ec8 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] (in AppKit)
>
> 40 0x00007fff90c89cd7 _os_activity_initiate (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
>
> 41 0x00007fff8d53d9a5 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
>
> 42 0x00007fff8d53cbd9 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
>
> 43 0x00007fff8d53c1b9 -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
>
> 44 0x00007fff8da3a2b1 -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:] (in AppKit)
>
> 45 0x00007fff8d4c0b4e -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
>
> 46 0x00007fff8d472e51 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
>
> 47 0x000000010f699600 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
>
> 48 0x00007fff8d2ff078 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
>
> 49 0x00007fff8d2ea464 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
>
> 50 0x00007fff8e1025c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
>
> 51 0x0000000000000001
>
> Performing @selector(goNextOrFinish:) from sender NSButton 0x7fd6b61c24d0
>
> abort() called
>
> osx-yosemite

Answer (score 1):

There may be better answers coming but if not.

I would either Partition the Hard drive and create a second bootable partition then use the older Xcode there.

Or Install it on a different Machine.

I support some apps on 10.6 and ran into similar problems and now use the older Xcode on another Machine. But have used Partitioning in the past for even older Xcodes.

In fact the Mac I am now has two Partitions for 10.10.x where one is for the Beta Version of Xcode.

[image]